# iOS custom navigation with dynamic navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uicontainerview

Im working on an application that needs to have a resizable navigation bar and in that case if the navigation bar's height increased, the `child view controller` inside the `navigation controller` should shrink. Here's the basic drawing:
[image]

What concept should I use to make this happen.

Im thinking about this n solutions:

- Create `Contaner view controller` which will have a view (used as a navigation bar) and a child view in which I'll insert `UINavigationController` without its navigation bar. The navigation hierarchy model will be managed inside this navigation controller. (view controllers stack)
- Create `Contaner view controller` which will have a view (used as a navigation bar) and a child view to show current view controller. In this case I'll need to handle the navigation by myself. (On web I didn't find any useful example for this case. I saw it being used mostly for cases of navigation between 2 or 3 view controllers. But not for more complex navigation.
- Subclass UINavigationController and inside of it I'll add a subview that will serve as a navigation bar. (I dont think this solution works, because I read on forums that frame of the child view controller cant be changed. Its managed by the system and cant be manipulated in any way)

What do you think? What approach should I use? Do you know a better way of custom navigation.

Comment: i think you need to check this :- https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/7blur and also https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/btnavigationdropdownmenu

Hope this helps.